# ASP.Net MVC: Css file reference's style is not applying on html when partial view returning as string

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a small partial view which has a css class reference at. from one of my action i am converting my partial view to string but i noticed css file reference is not working means css style, color nothing is applying on html inside partial view when check the output.

So when i hard code the same css style instead of css file reference in page then it worked.

So my question is if i refer css file in partial view instead of hard code style inside partial view then what i need to do as a result
style should be applied on html when i will check the partial view string ?

### The below routine return the string of partial view

```
public static class StringUtilities
{
    public static string RenderViewToString(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context, string viewPath, object model = null, bool partial = false)
    {
        // first find the ViewEngine for this view
        ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
        if (partial)
        {
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewPath);
        }
        else
        {
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewPath, null);
        }

        if (viewEngineResult == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found.");
        }

        // get the view and attach the model to view data
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;
        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        string result = null;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ctx = new ViewContext(context, view, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            view.Render(ctx, sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }

        return result.Trim();
    }
}
```

### this way i am getting string of the partial view

```
List<Student> studentsVM = new List<Student>
{
    new Student {ID=1,FirstName="Joy",      LastName="Roy",     FavouriteGames="Hocky"},
    new Student {ID=2,FirstName="Raja",     LastName="Basu",    FavouriteGames="Cricket"},
    new Student {ID=3,FirstName="Arijit",   LastName="Banerjee",FavouriteGames="Foot Ball"},
    new Student {ID=4,FirstName="Dibyendu", LastName="Saha",    FavouriteGames="Tennis"},
    new Student {ID=5,FirstName="Sanjeeb",  LastName="Das",     FavouriteGames="Hocky"},
};

var viewToString = StringUtilities.RenderViewToString(ControllerContext, "~/Views/Shared/_Report.cshtml", studentsVM, true);
```

**This is my partial view where i refer a css file whose style definition is not getting applied on partial view html.**

```
@model  List<TestBOL.Models.Student>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Student.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table" id="student">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name </th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th>Favourite Game</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach (var d in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@d.ID</td>
                <td>@d.FirstName</td>
                <td>@d.LastName</td>
                <td>@d.FavouriteGames</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Guide me what to do. thanks

Comment: First thing is , why your partial view contains html and head tags..You don't need to have head tag to include stylesheet reference. check if your console has error..and check if your css file is loaded. You can check it under sources tab in by pressing f12